# How to prevent two CUDA programs from interfering

Tags: cuda, locking, nvidia

I've noticed that if two users try to run CUDA programs at the same time, it tends to lock up either the card or the driver (or both?). We need to either reset the card or reboot the machine to restore normal behavior.

Is there a way to get a lock on the GPU so other programs can't interfere while it's running?

#### Edit

OS is Ubuntu 11.10 running on a server. While there is no X Windows running, the card is used to display the text system console. There are multiple users.

Comment: OS? Hardware? Is the system shared among many users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running on either Linux or Windows with the TCC driver, you can put the GPU into compute exclusive mode using the [`nvidia-smi` utility](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface).

Compute exclusive mode makes the driver refuse a context establishment request if another process already holds a context on that GPU. Any process trying to run on a busy compute exclusive GPU will receive a no device available error and fail.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the easiest to do. But I am unsure of the difference between EXCLUSIVE_THREAD and EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS. The man page is awkwardly written. *"EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS"  means  only  one  context is allowed per device, usable from multiple threads at a time.*

Comment: @BarryBrown: The difference is only whether context sharing from multiple threads in the same process is allowed, or only one thread has access to the GPU. In CUDA 4.0 and newer, the APIs were made thread safe, so that any thread from a process holding a context can access the GPU. Before that, contexts were tied to the thread which created them. You probably want to use `EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS` in about 99% of real-world cases. See as you are running without a display manager, you probably also want to look at persistence mode as well so that the driver doesn't unload when the GPU is idle.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll add `nvidia-smi -c EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS` to the boot script. It is already using persistence mode.

Comment: @talonmies I'm still a bit confused. The manual says about the compute mode that "Default" means multiple contexts are allowed per device." Doesn't it imply that multiple cuda programs are allowed to reside on the same device in Linux?

Comment: @KingCrimson: you did notice I was talking about exclusive mode and not default mode? These days there are two exclusive modes: "thread exclusive" and "process exclusive". They work exactly as I described in my answer, but at two different levels of granularity.

Comment: @talonmies: yes, i understand that the exclusive mode prevents other process or thread from accessing the device. But I wonder from the opposite perspective how multiple processes from different users may coexist -- execute concurrently or be queued elegantly -- on the device. A quick search has now led me to MPS daemon and Hyper Q function for the kepler gpus.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [Task Spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/) to queue the programs and run one at the time.

We use [TORQUE Resource Manager](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/) but it's harder to configure than `ts`. With TORQUE you can have multiple queues (ie one for cuda jobs, two for cpu jobs) and assign a different job to each gpu.